# Incrementing an array pointer using ++

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C, I know you can print different elements of an array like so

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
printf("%d", *(a+2));
```

but why does the following print statement result in error?

```
printf("%d", a++);
```

The error is:

```
error: cannot increment value of type 'int [5]'
```

I know `a` is of type array and you can't increment arrays, but isn't `a` also a pointer to the first element in the array?

Comment: `i<sizeof(a)` should be `i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`.

Comment: What do you mean by "result in error"? Does the compiler print an error message? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful in your responses

Comment: You make stack exchange such a wonderful community to want to contribute to and ask questions on!

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Actually, it is such a context. An array expression is converted to a pointer *unless* it's the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`, or a string literal used to initialize an array object. `a++` is not any of those contexts, so the conversion is done. The problem is that after the conversion, `a` is not an lvalue, so the `++` is invalid.

Comment: @KeithThompson oh yeah, right. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(a)` is the number of bytes an array occupies. You want e.g. `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`.

`a` decomposes into a pointer to the first element in the array if converted to one. As it's an array in your example, you shouldn't be able to increment it.

What you could do is:

```
int a[] = {...};
int *aptr = a; // a has decomposed into a pointer

aptr++; // etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `a` is an array, and you can't increment arrays.

You can increment pointer *objects*, but you can't increment pointer *values*. (Similarly, you can increment an integer object `i ++`, but you can't increment an integer value `42 ++`.)

Arrays **are not pointers**.  An expression of array type is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the first (0th) element of the corresponding array object. The resulting pointer is a pointer *value* (an address); no pointer *object* is created, so there's nothing to increment.

The `++` operator can be applied to a pointer expression, but only if it's a *modifiable lvalue*. (An *lvalue* is basically an expression that refers to an object. Not all lvalues are modifiable; for example, the name of a `const`-qualified object is not modifiable.)

Your statement that `a` is "also a pointer to the first element in the array" is partly correct, but potentially misleading. `a` is still the name of an array object, but the *expression* `a`, in this context does yield a pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that arrays (used in expressions) are not modifiable. It means that it can't be modified in any circumstances.

```
a = a+1; // WRONG  
a++;     // WRONG   
++a;     // WRONG
```

Comment: An *lvalue* is a kind of *expression*. An array object cannot be an lvalue, since it's not an expression. When you say "arrays", do you mean "expressions of array type"? In any case, after the array-to-pointer conversion, it's not an lvalue at all (it yields a *value* of pointer type; there is no pointer object for it to refer to).

Comment: @KeithThompson; Once I read about this non-modifiable lvalue [here](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/Non-modifiable%20Lvalues.htm).

Comment: Was that meant to answer my question?

Comment: An array expression, after the array-to-pointer conversion, is not an lvalue, modifiable or otherwise. N1570 6.3.2.1 paragraph 3.

Comment: @KeithThompson; I think there is a difference between `lvalue` and `non-modifiable` lvalue. When it is said that array expression is a non-modifiable lvalue then it means that it has an address but can't be modified. Something that is not an lvalue and not modifiable is rvalue. I think this term is used to differentiate it from rvalue.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point. As I said, after the array-to-pointer conversion, `a` is not an lvalue. Your answer says it is an lvalue. It is an expression of pointer type; there is no pointer object for it to refer to.

Comment: @KeithThompson; My answer says it is non-modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem.  It is neither a modifiable lvalue nor an unmodifiable lvalue. It **is not an lvalue at all**.  N1570 6.3.2.1 paragraph 3.